# Problem passing a list from Mathematica to external python function

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation, python

```
comp1a = Flatten[Join[{{0 + 0 i}}, {comp1}]];
Flatten[comp1a[[1 ;; 6]]]
```

This creates a list of complex values -> comp1a

The first 6 terms in the list are:

> {0, -2.04375 + 1.33694 I, -1.0492 + 3.3731 I, -4.95694 +
> 1.01694 I, 4.61625 - 4.52896 I, 6.66754 - 4.1488 I}

Then I try to pass the list to;

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "import numpy as np; timhist = np.fft.ifft(comp1a); timehist.tolist()"]
```

and the result is;

> Failure
> Message:"name 'comp1a' is not defined
> Tag:PythonError

My question is how do I feed a list developed in Mathematica to a python function called externally

Answer (score 8):

This will not work. Python does not know what `mylist` is:

```
mylist = {1, 2, 3, 4};
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "sum(mylist)"]
```

You must get the value of `mylist` into Python somehow. This could be done with string replacement:

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "sum(" <>
  StringReplace[ToString[mylist], {"{" -> "[", "}" -> "]"}]
  <> ")"]
```

... though as Jason .B noted in the comments, it's much simpler to write this as a `TemplateExpression`:

```
ExternalEvaluate["Python", "sum(<* mylist *>)"]
```

For complex numbers, you'll need to rewrite them as a `complex` type first before you can feed them to Python:

```
createcomplex[z_?NumericQ] := 
 "complex(" <> ToString[Re[z]] <> "," <> ToString[Im[z]] <> ")"

createcomplex[-2.7 + 3.5 I]
(* result: "complex(-2.7,3.5)" *)
```

Or more simply, using templates:

```
toPyComplexStr[z_?NumericQ] := 
 TemplateApply["complex(<* Re[z] *>, <* Im[z] *>)", z]
```

There is however, a better way in the [documentation](https://wolfram.com/xid/0h2l99v7e8-730is1) which doesn't depend on text substitution and it uses an external session:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];
ExternalEvaluate[session, <|
  "Command" -> "sum",
  "Arguments" -> {NumericArray[{1 + I, 2.3 - I, 5.7 - 2.3 I, 7}, 
     "ComplexReal32"]}
  |>]
(* result: 16. - 2.3 I *)
```

---

Let's use it for your problem:

```
session = StartExternalSession["Python"];
result = Last@
  ExternalEvaluate[
   session, {"import numpy as np", <|"Command" -> "np.fft.ifft", 
     "Arguments" -> {NumericArray[{0, -2.04375 + 1.33694 I, -1.0492 + 
          3.3731 I, -4.95694 + 1.01694 I, 4.61625 - 4.52896 I, 
         6.66754 - 4.1488 I}, "ComplexReal32"]}|>}]
Normal[result]
(* result: {0.538983 - 0.491797 I, -1.01814 - 2.38259 I, -1.15996 + 0.0605042 I, 
 0.650033 + 0.10651 I, -1.85749 + 0.939762 I, 2.84658 + 1.76761 I} *)
```

... and notice that this result matches up with `InverseFourier` if you use `FourierParameters -> {1, -1}`:

```
InverseFourier[{0, -2.04375 + 1.33694 I, -1.0492 + 3.3731 I, -4.95694 + 1.01694 I, 4.61625 - 4.52896 I, 6.66754 - 4.1488 I}, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]

(* result: {0.538983 - 0.491797 I, -1.01814 - 2.38259 I, -1.15996 + 0.0605042 I, 
 0.650033 + 0.10651 I, -1.85749 + 0.939762 I, 2.84658 + 1.76761 I} *)
```

Comment: try `ExternalEvaluate["Python", "sum(<* mylist *>)"]`

Comment: Thanks Jason, that's a TemplateExpression right?

Comment: That seems to be the case.  I usually forget what the syntax every time, and scramble around for the chat log where I learned it.  Now I know it has a name, and it's listed in the details section for `ExternalEvaluate`

Comment: Thanks Jason. Your expression works for Real values. Now I just need to convert things to work with complex numbers

Comment: @tomhouston - look at the last bit of code in this answer.  If you create a complex-valued `NumericArray` you can pass it into python (using the short or long syntax) and it will be typed correctly.

Comment: @tomhouston I've provided a solution for your ifft and shown it's identical to `InverseFourier` with parameters `{1,-1}` (up to very small numerical error)